# System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'A task was canceled.' when Closing App

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have a thread that change the field

```
private void SongChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SongChangeAction();
        songLength = (int)BGMPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        songProgress = new Thread(SongProgressUpdate) { IsBackground = true };
        songProgress.Start();
    }

    private void SongProgressUpdate()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { workingResources.SongProgress = BGMPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds / songLength * 100; });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Note: `songLength` is a `double`, `BGMPlayer` is a `MediaElement` to play music in background, `workingResources.SongProgress` is a `double` bind to a `Progress Bar`

When I close the Program using "X" button or on taskbar, The program threw exception `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` Even I try to set the thread `IsBackground = true` but it work not throw exception If I stop the program using Visual Studio.
The Program Throw exception at line:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { workingResources.SongProgress = BGMPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds / songLength * 100; });
```

I can prevent it by using try/catch but I want to find something more efficient

Comment: That's expected exception in your situation. When you close main window - WPF gracefully shuts down. If you try to do `Dispatcher.Invoke` when dispatcher started shutting down - it will throw exception you see. You can either switch to `BeginInvoke`, catch that exception, or, better - use another ways to achieve your goal which do not require `Dispatcher.Invoke`, separate thread, and `while (true)` loops.

Comment: BGMPlayer is a Controls. If I use another thread a use while  loop then the app will thrown Thread.InvalidOperation

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `CancellationToken` on close of the window:

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _shutDown = new CancellationTokenSource();

public WindowName()
{
    this.Closed =+ (s, e) => this._shutDown.Cancel();
}

private void SongChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SongChangeAction();
    songLength = (int)BGMPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    songProgress = Task.Factory.StartNew(SongProgressUpdate, this._shutDown.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}

private void SongProgressUpdate()
{
    while (!this._shutDown.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { workingResources.SongProgress = BGMPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds / songLength * 100; });
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Then you can do this:

```
private void SongChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SongChangeAction();
    songLength = (int)BGMPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    IDisposable subscription =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(x => workingResources.SongProgress = BGMPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds / songLength * 100);
}
```

You just need to make sure that you save a reference to `subscription` and call `.Dispose()` on it when you are closing your app.

NuGet "System.Reactive" and "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading", and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to your code.